# How to run rails automatically on ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx

I have a server at digitalocean and have installed rails. Now I can run it just fine by having my terminal open and running the command. However, I don't want my computer to be on 24h, so I need some way of running it automatically. As a Front-End dev I don't have too much knowledge of setting up nginx or so. Is there any easy and fast way to do it?

Comment: The server at digital ocean is available 24/7, your computer is irrelevant. You'll most likely find how to setup your Rails application on digitalocean help center: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/community_tags/ruby-on-rails

Comment: My computer is relevant as I am connected via ssh and runnig the command via the terminal. If I close the terminal, the server also shuts down as the user executing it logged out.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of options.  You can run it from your terminal using the `nohup` command or the `screen` command.  `nohup` is a simpler command.  You should be able to do `man nohup` at the command line to see the instructions for that.  Basically you should be able to run:

`nohup whatever-your-command-to-start-nginx-is &`

and nginx will start.  The man page will tell you that standard  output will go to `nohup.out` in the current directory, or $HOME if that's not possible (but nginx normal logging stuff should go to wherever it's config file tells it).  The ampersand at the end just means that the command will be run in the background so you get your prompt back (though a normal nginx start would do that anyway, so it's probably not needed).  nohup means the command won't exit when you quit your terminal ("no hang-up").

The nicer way to do it would be to use an init script.  You may already have one depending on how you installed nginx.  Is there an `/etc/init.d/nginx` file?  If so, `/etc/init.d/nginx start` should start nginx, and `/etc/init.d/nginx stop` should stop it.  If not, you can get hold of one somewhere.  Have a look at http://wiki.nginx.org/InitScripts

You can also set things up so that it starts automatically on system boot (using the init script).  If the installation of nginx did already give you the init script, then this might also have been set up for you.  (The key word for google here is probably "runlevels".)

These days in Ubuntu, I believe that `upstart` is preferred for handling services including starting them at boot (I think it can also do other stuff, like restarting services that die).  However, I don't really have any experience with it and this question on serverfault seems to indicate mixed experiences with it and nginx:

https://serverfault.com/questions/143461/how-can-i-start-nginx-via-upstart/391737

(though it's a pretty old question)